# Run a previous command changing one argument

Tags: zsh, history

Given a command in my history, how can I run the same command changing one argument?

For example, if command 34 is `script.sh a b c`, how can I run the command `script.sh a fff c` using some kind of parameter substitution?

Assume that, in real life, `b` is not easy to type, so using the generic string substitution mechanism isn't reasonable. I know that I can use edit-and-execute, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't require opening a text editor. I presume there's something like `!34:blahblahblah`, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried reading the manual for zsh substitutions, but I get the feeling that I don't know what keywords to look for.

EDIT: I know about history and editing the comment using readline or edit-and-execute. I'm looking for something more like "the same as command 34, but change the third parameter to `blah`, similar to how the one can write `!34:3` to refer to a parameter on command 34.

Comment: Have you tried the up arrow key? Most shells could re-use old commands by pressing up and down arrow keys, much like scrolling through the commands.

Comment: Event better to search through you history, use `reverse-i-search`, with `Ctrl + R`.

Comment: I know how to find a previous conmand. I've tried to clarify my question above.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I can think of is the quite cumbersome

```
 !!:0-2 new-argument !!:4
```

The `!!:0-2` repeats the command and its first two arguments, the `!!:4` is the last argument of the last command (which can be also written as `!$` if you prefer).

Comment: Ugh. I hoped for something better. I guess edit-and-execute becomes the option of least resistance for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact las command we can do:

```
^b^fff
```

Use the caret symbol to indicate what you want to substitute and the substitution.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, I want to change a command earlier in my history and I don't want to match `b`, because in general that's a long string to match.